# How do I know if koboldcpp is using my GPU?

Tags: nvidia, ubuntu-18.04, cublas, koboldai

I have compiled koboldcpp from source on Ubuntu 18.04 using:

```
git clone https://github.com/LostRuins/koboldcpp
cd koboldcpp
make -j10 koboldcpp_cublas LLAMA_OPENBLAS=1 LLAMA_CUBLAST=1
```

But when it loads it does not use my GPU (I checked using nvidia-smi and it's at 0%). It uses CPU only.

```
koboldcpp3  | Identified as LLAMA model: (ver 1)
koboldcpp3  | System Info: AVX = 1 | AVX2 = 1 | AVX512 = 0 | AVX512_VBMI = 0 | AVX512_VNNI = 0 | FMA = 1 | NEON = 0 | ARM_FMA = 0 | F16C = 1 | FP16_VA = 0 | WASM_SIMD = 0 | BLAS = 0 | SSE3 = 1 | SSSE3 = 1 | VSX = 0 |
```

Does koboldcpp log explicitly whether it is using the GPU, i.e. `printf("I am using the GPU\n");` vs `printf("I am using the CPU\n");` so I can learn it straight from the horse's mouth instead of relying on external tools such as `nvidia-smi`?

Should I look for `BLAS = 1` in the `System Info` log?

Answer (score 0):

Hm, according to https://github.com/LostRuins/koboldcpp/discussions/21:

> This tool currently only focuses on CPU inference, you may want to check out this repo instead for GPU inference for llama: https://github.com/0cc4m/KoboldAI

I guess I have been wasting my time trying to get the GPU to work with koboldcpp